# Certificate chain received from translation.googleapis.com

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, certificate, weblogic12c, google-translation-api

I want to use Google Translation API in my Java Web App.
I have imported the certificate from `https://translation.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v3` in cacerts.jks , but it doesn't work. 
I am using Weblogic 12c and my Java version is jdk1.8.0_221

This is the server log:

```
Certificate chain received from translation.googleapis.com -
   172.217.6.138 failed hostname verification check. 
   Certificate contained *.storage.googleapis.com but 
   check expected translation.googleapis.com

Hostname verification failed:
   HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier,
   hostname=translation.googleapis.com.
```

Comment: The google server certificate is correct, but a quick search for `weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier` seems to show that it is unapologetically broken by design, conforming to no reasonable behavior, and is incorrectly failing to validate the cert according to standard practice and blaming the "chain" (which is not the problem, either)... but there's also `weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSWildcardHostnameVerifier` mentioned at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SECMG/hostname_verifier.htm#SECMG575 which might do what you want.  See if that helps?

Comment: Thanks  Michael, now Im going to do a webservice client to custom translation.googleapis.com service. When I finish i try to configure my weblogic server as at link that you sended me